# anchor links in office365 outlook web app

Tags: outlook, anchor, html-email, office365

We have discovered that anchor links does not work properly in outlooks web app in office365. The anchor links does not work in all email clients but at least it renders nicely and not like in outlook where it looks like this:

```
[#Android]Android (10 articles)
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this? I tried Google, but didn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't target anchor links in email, each ESP is going to react different to them. I've been hearing a ton of bad things about office365 and the new outlook.com with anchor links.

Comment: Has Microsoft commented this or anything? Do you know where i can find any more information about this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work in the latest version of Office365 that is online, so at least for me it got fixed by Microsoft now.